# Notice: Undefined index: ¿Porque me marca ese error?

Tags: php, html

Estoy generando un registro de logueo estoy integrando `session_start();` tengo un inconveniente me marca un error el cual es el siguiente:  `Notice: Undefined index: tiempo in C:\xampp\htdocs\revista\rev\administrador\consultar_registros.php on line 26`, la linea 26 es la siguiente: `if(time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 18000) {` les dejo el código que estoy utilizando, espero me ayuyden a resolver este problema ya que no encuentro a que se deba me estoy volviendo loca con esto y no se como solucionarlo.

**funciones.php**

```
public function verificar_login($nombre_usuario, $password){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario where nombre_usuario ='$nombre_usuario' and password = '$password' ";
        $result = $this->conecta()->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'] = $row['nombre_usuario'];
                $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
                $_SESSION["autentificado"] = "SI";
                $_SESSION['start'] = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
                $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
                if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                    header("Location:consultar_registros.php");
                }
            }else{
                echo '<script language="javascript">
                alert("Los datos son incorrectos vuelve a intentarlo");
                window.location.href="../administrador/index.php";
                </script>';
        }
    }
```

**consultar_registros.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 18000) { ---Aquí es donde me indica que esta el error---
  echo '<script language="javascript">
      alert("Debes de registrarte para poder ingresar");
      window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';
  session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: Indica que en tu variable `$_SESSION` no hay ninguna clave llamada `tiempo`. Generalmente en esto se usa `isset`, para comprobar la existencia de esa clave. Ejemplo `if (isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])){//tu código}else{echo "No existe la clave tiempo en la sesión";}`. Para verificar lo que hay dentro puedes hacer un `print_r($_SESSION);`, lo cual te mostrará todo el contenido de tu sesión.

Comment: cual es la linea 26???

Comment: @francisco Nuñez indique al inicio de la pregunta cual era la linea 26 (la linea 26 es la siguiente: if(time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 18000) {) y se encuentra en el apartado de consultar_registros.php

Comment: ese error me ha ocurrido y es por que se me olvido crear la columna en la tabla o el nombre no coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese error es propio de PHP y se produce cuando intentas acceder a un valor de un array usando un índice inexistente, en tu caso:

```
$_SESSION['tiempo']
```

no existe donde intentas acceder al mismo. Puedes hacer un ***debug*** de *$_SESSION* en cualquier momento para ver que contiene:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Sin embargo, y como norma general, ya que su contenido puede variar, para evitar errores como el que obtienes se controla que contenga un indice determinado antes de tratar de acceder a él:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) {
    // acciones
} else {
    // otras acciones
}
```

En tu caso concreto, seguramente cuando intentas acceder al valor de $_SESSION, la función que inicializa el valor, no fue llamada o quizá el valor o todos los valores contenidos en $_SESSION fueron borrados en otro punto del programa, antes de tratar de acceder al mismo.

Puedes cambiar tu código para obtener info sobre el fallo y que no se genere el fallo en sí, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])) {
    //
    // Aquí puedes mostrar un mensaje que te avise durante el desarrollo 
    // o bien generar un log de error
    //

} elseif(time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 18000) { ---Aquí es donde me indica que esta el error---
  echo '<script language="javascript">
      alert("Debes de registrarte para poder ingresar");
      window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';
  session_destroy();
}
```

sin embargo, debes dar con la causa del problema, si lo es. Si sólo estas comprobando si se inicio sesión y es perfectamente normal que no se haya invocado la función ***verificar_login()*** evitaras el error solo con cambiar tu línea problemática:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) && ((time() - $_SESSION['tiempo']) > 18000)) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al sustituir tu código en el mio funciona de maravilla, ya no me muestra el error, pero ahora me ingresa a la pagina de consultar_registros.php sin estar registrado y eso es lo quiero tratar de evitar

Comment: De nada, puedes votar mi respuesta si la encuentras de utilidad o darla como válida si resolvio tu problema. Un saludo.